# Modify widget to output posts in custom order

Tags: loop

I am using a widget of the Smartline-Lite theme called "Smartline_Category_Posts_Grid_Widget" that lists posts of a chosen category on the front page. I have set the number of posts to 10.

The widget takes the latest 10 posts of that category and outputs them in the default reverse-chroronological order. Please see bottom of my site (http://www.orandanow.com) for the widget output result.

Now what I want is to be able to put some kind of numerical marker on the posts of that category (eg: 1, 2, 3, etc.) so that the widget takes the latest 10 posts and lists them in ascending order of the numerical markers. Thus, the latest 10 posts of that category are listed not in reverse-chronological order, but in the numerical marker order.

Can someone please advise how this might be implemented? I am pasting the part of the widget code which I think runs the loop. If you want to see the whole code, let me know.

```
// Render Widget Content
function render( $settings ) {

    // Get latest posts from database
    $query_arguments = array(
        'posts_per_page' => (int)$settings['number'],
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'cat' => (int)$settings['category']
    );
    $posts_query = new WP_Query( $query_arguments );
    $i = 0;

    // Check if there are posts
    if( $posts_query->have_posts() ) :

        // Limit the number of words for the excerpt
        add_filter('excerpt_length', 'smartline_frontpage_category_excerpt_length');

        // Display Posts
        while( $posts_query->have_posts() ) :

            $posts_query->the_post(); 

             // Open new Row on the Grid
             if ( $i % 2 == 0) : ?>

                <div class="category-posts-grid-row clearfix">

            <?php // Set Variable row_open to true
                $row_open = true;
            endif; ?>

            <?php // Display small posts or big posts grid layout based on options
            if( $settings['thumbnails'] == true ) : ?>

                <div class="small-post-wrap">

                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('small-post clearfix'); ?>>

                    <?php if ( '' != get_the_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category_posts_small_thumb'); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                        <div class="small-post-content">
                            <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title post-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>
                            <div class="entry-meta postmeta"><?php $this->display_postmeta( $settings ); ?></div>
                        </div>

                    </article>

                </div>

            <?php else: ?>

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('big-post'); ?>>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category_posts_wide_thumb'); ?></a>

                    <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h1 class="entry-title post-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h1>' ); ?>

                    <div class="entry-meta postmeta"><?php $this->display_postmeta( $settings ); ?></div>

                    <div class="entry">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>

                </article>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php // Close Row on the Grid
            if ( $i % 2 == 1) : ?>

                </div>

            <?php // Set Variable row_open to false
                $row_open = false;

            endif; $i++;

        endwhile;

        // Close Row if still open
        if ( $row_open == true ) : ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif;

        // Remove excerpt filter
        remove_filter('excerpt_length', 'smartline_frontpage_category_excerpt_length');

    endif;
```

I am not a programmer, so go easy php-lingo please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you just need HTML ol tag. No PHP

Comment: @Jevuska, I think the question is about ordering posts, not numbering their appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that code, it doesn't look like there are any filters that would allow you to do what you're hoping. This isn't particularly surprising...

Taking a step back, Posts are inherently intended to contain chronologically-ordered content, so it's unusual for plugins to allow ordering of posts by anything other than their published date. If you're needing to do this, I'd strongly consider finding a solution where your content is stored in pages or a custom post type. Pages, for instance, have a field called Menu Order that is exactly intended for what you describe. This field is not available on Posts. (Note: It's possible that [Post Types Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/) would let you do this, but then the order of posts you set would be reflected *everywhere*, not just in the widget.)

I'd recommend finding a different widget that allows this. The one I know off the top of my head is [Query Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-posts/screenshots/), though it would be cumbersome. You'd collect and order the IDs of each post you want, and enter them in the `post__in` field of the widget settings. Then you'd set the `orderby` field to `post__in`. ([Flexible Posts Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flexible-posts-widget/) may also allow this.)

Comment: Thank you for your insight, mrwweb.  That's a bummer knowing it can't be done the way I wanted to.  I was hoping for something like putting numerical tag on the article, and when the loop runs, it gathers the 10 articles first, and then reorders them according to the tag numbers before outputing them.  Just a shot in the dark...

Comment: Just to be clear, what you describe is possible, but I don't think you're going to find a plugin widget that does it. It would require a custom-coded one.

Comment: I see...so how would it be implemented then?  Would it work using the numerical tags idea I proposed, or is there a more efficient way?  Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to write your own custom widget and set up a post_meta system for the ordering which is way outside the scope of a single WPSE question.